# How to see if x kbps of information can be transmitted with shannons theorem

Tags: physics

I found this question on the web:

'We are given a medium that will reliably transmit frequencies between 0 and 25,000Hz. Is it possible to transmit 200Kbps of information along this line?'

What I am wondering is if we can check this with Shannons theorem, if yes could anyone give me some help since im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Nyquist-Shannon theorem](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Paper_2/Fundamentals_of_data_representation/Nyquist-theorem).

**Nyquist's theorem** - the sample rate should be at a frequency which is at least twice the value of the highest frequency in the sampled signal.